# How can i install peerguardian?

Tags: wireless, software-installation, tar, ip

I tried to install PeerGuardian and expected it to be a simple run and install... but its a tar.gz! I’m completely new to Linux and have no idea what that is, how to install it, or how safe it is! Can some one help me?

Also I’ve heard PeerGuardian blocks your wifi connection, so if there is any one fluent with PeerGuardian I would appreciate your help as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open a terminal and type: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jre-phoenix/ppa`

Followed by: `sudo apt-get update`

and `sudo apt-get install pgld pglcmd pglgui`

Source: http://sourceforge.net/p/peerguardian/wiki/pgl-Install-DebianUbuntu/

Comment: Many times Ubuntu is simpler than one thinks.